# Return JS source code from PHP

Tags: javascript, php, laravel-4

On website I have embedded some Script

`<script src="somesite.com/getCode.php"></script>`

And when the request is made I want to return JavaScript code from 'getCode.php'.

How should I return it from PHP?

Comment: put `header("content-type: application/javascript");`

Answer (score 1):

Well, you have to do something like this:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
   <?php echo file_get_contents("somesite.com/getCode.php"); ?>
</script>
```

Make sure the path to the file is correct.

Comment: Why would you output js code into the src attribute?

Answer (score 0):

You just need to output the correct header for js, then output the js:

```
<?php
$somevar = 'hello from php via js';
header('Content-Type: application/javascript');
?>
alert('<?php echo $somevar;?>');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
// Filename: getCode.php
header("content-type: application/javascript");
echo 'function foo(){ console.log("Foo is running"); }';
die();
```

or

```
<?php
// Filename: getCode.php
header("content-type: application/javascript");
?>
// your js code in plain text
function foo(){ console.log("Foo is running"); }
```

For understanding media-type (aka content-type) you should read this RFC at section 7
http://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4329.txt